# Change background color in a specific widget of a Qt Stacked Widget

Tags: qt, widget, qt-creator, qstackedwidget

I am developing a Qt application using Qt Creator that is based on a stacked widget. I would like to independently change the background color of each page of the stacked widget (e.g. first page blue, second page red, etc.). However, when I add `background-color:` to the styleSheet tab on Qt creator, the result is that all the pages of the stacked widget get that background color. Is there a way to set a different background color to each page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it per widget:

```
#page1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
#page2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Where `#page1` and `#page2` are the object names, find them on the Object Inspector side panel in Qt Creator.

Comment: That was easy! Just couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
// yep, you can change it in constructor of your widget.
YourWidget::YourWidget(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent),ui(new Ui::PageControl)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPalette background(palette());
    background.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::black);
    this->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    this->setPalette(background);
}
```